# Chrome Extension - Running Sequential functions through promises not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, promise, es6-promise

I have a chrome extension (JS) that I am building and when the user clicks on a button in the popup, the extension updates the chrome.storage.local to reflect what is on the popup and (in theory) when that is complete, it would run three content scripts. Unfortunately, the content script seem to start before the information is set in the popup.js.

I have tried Timeouts and Promises, however with both, it still runs the next function before the "chrome.storage.local.set" (in the updateStorage() function) is executed. Is there a better method/something that I am missing?

popup.js

```
console.log("popup.js");
function doContent() {
  console.log("content1");
  //checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  //checkCheckboxes(checkboxes);
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_addNote.js" });
}
function checkCheckboxes(checkboxes, orderArray) {
  //console.log("checkboxes");
  //console.log(checkboxes);
  console.log("orderArray");
  console.log(orderArray);
  console.log("for loop running");
  var ii = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked === false) {
        console.log(i, orderArray[i], "will be removed for the list");
        //console.log(orderArray[i]);

        orderArray.splice(ii, 1);
        ii = ii - 1;
        console.log(orderArray);
      }
      ii += 1;
      //console.log(i, checkboxes[i].checked);
    }
  }
  console.log("for loop ended");
  console.log("Output from checkCheckboxes");
  console.log(orderArray);
  return orderArray;
}

function updateStorage() {
  console.log("updateStorage");
  var emailSelect = document.getElementById("SelEmailType");
  var emailType = emailSelect.options[emailSelect.selectedIndex].id;
  if (document.getElementById("itemInfo").innerHTML === "Placeholder") {
    console.log("Error. Placeholder not found");
  } else {
    var storedLegal = chrome.storage.local.get("newStorage", function (items) {
      var newArray = { ...items };
      console.log(newArray);
      var orderList = items.newStorage.src_items;
      console.log("orderList", orderList);
      //console.log("indexOf", orderList.indexOf("\n"));
      var orderArray = orderList.split("\n");
      var checkboxes = new Array();
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      updatedOrder = checkCheckboxes(checkboxes, orderArray);

      console.log(updatedOrder);
      arraString = updatedOrder.join("\n");
      //console.log(arraString);
      //alert(arraString);
      newArray.newStorage.src_items = arraString;
      newArray.newStorage.src_emailType = emailType;
      console.log("start newArray");
      console.log(newArray);
      console.log("end newArray");

      console.log(newArray.newStorage);
      chrome.storage.local.clear();
      chrome.storage.local.set({
        newStorage: newArray.newStorage,
      });
      //chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ newStorage: newArray.newStorage });
      console.log("stored");
      //console.log(chrome.runtime.local.get({ newStorage }));
    });
  }
  console.log("End storedLegal");
  return;
}

function one_by_one(objects_array, iterator, callback) {
  /* var x = 1;
  var y = null; // To keep under proper scope
  setTimeout(function () {
    x = x * 3 + 2;
    y = x / 2;
  }, 500); */
  var start_promise = objects_array.reduce(function (prom, object) {
    return prom.then(function () {
      //var y = null; // To keep under proper scope
      /*       setTimeout(function () {
        x = x * 3 + 2;
        y = x / 2;
      }, 500);
      x = 1;
      y = null; */
      return chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: object }); //iterator(object);
    });
  }, Promise.resolve()); // initial
  if (callback) {
    start_promise.then(callback);
  } else {
    return start_promise;
  }
}
/* 
function processArray(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce(
    (p, v) => p.then((a) => fn(v).then((r) => a.concat([r]))),
    Promise.resolve([])
  );
} */

function doContent2() {
  console.log("doContent2");

  updateStorage();

  fileFunctions = [
    "content2.js",
    "content_addShippingNote.js",
    "content_addNote.js",
    "disconnect.js",
  ];
  var x = 1;
  var y = null; // To keep under proper scope

  console.log("fileFunctions ");
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Promise #1
    updateStorage();
    console.log("Promise #1 ");
    setTimeout(function () {
      x = x * 3 + 2;
      y = x / 2;
    }, 1000);
    resolve();
  })
    .then((result) => {
      var storedLegal = chrome.storage.local.get("newStorage", function (
        items
      ) {
        if ((items = undefined)) {
          console.log("item not found");
          // To keep under proper scope
          setTimeout(function () {
            x = 1;
            y = null;
            x = x * 3 + 2;
            y = x / 2;
          }, 500);
        }

        //console.log(items);
      });
      // Promise #2
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content2.js" });

      console.log("Promise #2 ");
      return result;
    })
    .then((result) => {
      // Promise #3
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_addShippingNote.js" });
      console.log("Promise #3 ");
      return result;
    })
    .then((result) => {
      // Promise #3
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_addNote.js" });
      console.log("Promise #4 ");
      return result;
    });
  //processArray(fileFunctions, runScript).then(console.log);
  //fileFunctions.forEach(runScript);
  //one_by_one(fileFunctions, "", "");

  /*  var promised = new Promise(updateStorage).then((result, err) => {
    console.log("YA");
    fileFunctions.forEach(runScript);
  }); */

  document.getElementById("btnCreateEmail").addEventListener("click", null);
  //fileFunctions.forEach(runScript);
  /*   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content2.js" }),
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_addShippingNote.js" }),
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_addNote.js" }),
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "disconnect.js" }), */
}

function runScript(fileName, index) {
  console.log(index, ": ", fileName);
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: fileName });
}

function clearStorage() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "disconnect.js" });
  alert("local cleared");
}

function orderToHTML(orderList) {
  var orderArray = orderList.split("\n");

  // Draw HTML table
  var perrow = 2, // cells per row
    html = "<table><tbody>";

  // Loop through array and add table cells
  for (var i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
    html +=
      "<tr><td><input type=" &
      "checkbox" &
      " " &
      "id=" &
      i &
      "/></td><td>" &
      orderArray[i] &
      "</td></tr>";

    var next = i + 1;
    if (next % perrow == 0 && next != orderArray.length) {
      html += "</tr><tr>";
    }
  }
  html += "</tbody></table>";
  // Attach HTML to container
  return html;
}
function setWaitPeriod(time) {
  var x = 1;
  var y = null; // To keep under proper scope
  setTimeout(function () {
    x = x * 3 + 2;
    y = x / 2;
  }, time);
}
//window.onload = function () {

//console.log("window.onload");
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ popupOpen: true });
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender) => {
  // First, validate the message's structure.
  if (msg.from === "content" && msg.subject === "showPageAction") {
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = msg.container;
    document.getElementById("itemInfo").innerHTML = msg.itemInfo;
  }
});

document.getElementById("btnCreateEmail").addEventListener("click", doContent2);
//document.getElementById("btnClear").addEventListener("click", clearStorage);
//});
```

Comment: Every method in `chrome` API that can accept a callback is asynchronous so in order to run sequentially you need to call the next code in the callback of the previous API call. In other words you'll have to rewrite everything. To simplify the code you can use [webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) and the modern async/await syntax.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm. I did some reading and found that the storage.local.get has a callback that I was able to use.
```
chrome.storage.local.set({
        newStorage: newArray.newStorage,
      }, function(){
//next routine goes here
})